# $(element).height() = element.clientHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are these two the same thing?

Because they appear to return the same value from my tests.

I'm trying to optimize some of my code to use native js properties...

Comment: The short answer is not always. Web Browsers...

Comment: Answer here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) does not include padding, margin, or border.

[`clientHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533563%28VS.85%29.aspx) includes padding but not border, margin or scrollbar.